# TortoiseSVN access denied wile preparing for commit(Win7)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN 1.7.11, Build 23600 - 64 Bit , 2012/12/12 19:08:52
Subversion 1.7.8

OS: Win7 SP1

On commit I get following messages:

*Commit failed (details follow):
While preparing
 '...'
 for commit
Access denied*

Folder has all permissions for current user.
Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have an on-access virus scanner that's enabled & getting in the way? Can you try committing from the command-line to see if you get the same error?

Comment: No, the interesting fact is that if I commit specified file alone it works.
From console its the same:

Transmitting file data...svn: E220001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E220001: Access denied

Comment: It is probably a problem with your authz access rules (or a bug in the server). Is it possible that you checked out your working copy using upper case somewhere in the URL, and the authz rule specifies lower case somewhere in the path (or a similar incorrect-case situation?

Comment: No that's not the case, I used TortoiseSVN for a long time with no problems, and problems only appear now.

Comment: Try clearing your auth data: `TortoiseSVN Settings -> SavedData -> Authentication Data -> Clear` and re-authenticating with the server by using the `Repository Browser` - if that works, then try committing again

Comment: I was experiencing a very similar problem. It occurred after creating a new directory in my repo. My solution was similar to Nik's. I performed a fresh checkout (got latest from trunk) created a new branch (with a similar name, for reference), and moved all my files over to that branch. It's a bit hacky (because I'm sure there's another way to do it -- I just ran out of time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with server side permissions, but with local permissions.
I'd moved some files from one folder to another and TortoiseSVN didn't change it's svn path for some reason.

Finally solution was the following:

1. Upload this file manually to SVN.
2. Fresh checkout to another folder
3. Substitute old .svn folder with new one